# Communicate with different Client Libraries

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All.

now, I understand concept of node.

[this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes) shows that below.

```
ROS client libraries allow nodes written in different programming languages to communicate:

rospy = python client library
roscpp = c++ client library
```

And, rosjava uses node also.

So I think rosjava node communicate with roscpp node.

Is It right?

I cannot see the tutorial that communicate with rosjava and roscpp.. TT

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41314/communicate-with-different-client-libraries/) by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2012-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All languages have tutorials using similar topic publisher and subscribers, service providers and client. So you can start the talker node from a rosjava tutorial and use it with a listener node from a c++ tutorial.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SanghaNam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2025/sanghanam/) on 2012-08-16**:
thank you very much .. you are really kind ^^